# List all registered controls of template driven form inside test class

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular4-forms

```
  <form #form="ngForm">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput ngModel placeholder="Starting price" name="startingPrice">
      </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

accessing this template driven form in my component like this

```
 @ViewChild('form') myForm: NgForm;
```

but I fail to list them because the template loads after I call console.log

```
  it('should list registered form controls', (() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
    console.log('input', component.myForm.form.controls);
  }));
```

How should I wait in my test, so that I can access the form.controls list?

Tried this, but to no avail

```
 it('should be defined', fakeAsync(() => {
    // This first detectChanges is necessary to properly set up the form
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Tick needs to be called in order for form controls to be registered properly.
    tick();

    expect(fixture).toBeDefined();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance).toBeDefined();

    let myForm: NgForm = fixture.componentInstance.myForm;
    console.log('myForm.controls.startingPrice', myForm.form.controls['startingPrice']); // still getting undefined

  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

**MatOptionModule** was not imported into test.
Causing injected form to be invalid.

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #form="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Pick" name="selectSomething" ngModel>
      <mat-option value="E">Express</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="C">Combined</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput name="startingPrice">
  </mat-form-field>

</form>



 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MatCardModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatOptionModule, 
        RouterTestingModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [TestComponent]// declare the test component
    })
      .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
  }));
```